# How do I get Edit Profile to not save with invalid date input on Joomla Community Builder

Tags: sql, community-builder, validation

On my volunteering website, users can edit their profile and enter a date in the future when they are available to volunteer. If they are already signed up for a volunteer opportunity, they shouldn't be able to change the dates they are available until they have fulfilled their assignment. I am using CB Query Validation to check if they have a current assignment when they change their date. The validation is working - that is, it is showing the error message when they change the date but shouldn't be changing it. But it still allows them to save the profile edit with the new date. Is there a way to disable the SAVE button if the error shows?

Comment: Originally posted on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69105575/2943403

Comment: I am not a CB user but can the Query Validation that checks if they have an assignment already be altered so that it makes the date field readonly to prevent them changing the field. Or conversely you make the Date field readonly by default and if they don't have an assignment then you remove the readonly and make it available to be updated.

Comment: Ended up just hiding the field if the condition of having a current assignment was true.